# How to compare numbers in two files and save the differences into one of files using bash?

Tags: bash

```
$> cat file1.txt
15,20,8,

$> cat file2.txt
10,20,30,
```

There is only one line in the files. I wanted to compare comma-separated numbers in two files and save the difference to right next to the old value.

So, using `file1.txt` as a base, after comparing to `file2.txt`, I would expect to see:

```
15(+5),20,8(-22),
```

Would it be possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What have you done so far?

Comment: How do you compare these two files ? Try to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

bash is not best for such issue, but still doable, some thing like this:

```
AA="15,20,8"
BB="10,20,30"

IFS=","
declare -a A=($AA)
declare -a B=($BB)

for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do
    if [ ${A[$i]} -eq ${B[$i]} ]; then
        echo -n ${A[$i]},
    else
        echo -n ${A[$i]}'('$((${A[$i]}-${B[$i]}))')',
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# progname: diffcalc
# syntax:   diffcalc file1.txt file2.txt
#
# last element in file1.txt must always be a comma

read LINE1 < "$1"
read LINE2 < "$2"

while [ "$LINE1" ]                          #while LINE1 is not empty
do
    DIFF=$(( ${LINE1%%,*} - ${LINE2%%,*} )) #diff between first elements
    [ $DIFF -gt 0 ] && OUT="(+$DIFF)"
    [ $DIFF -eq 0 ] && OUT=""
    [ $DIFF -lt 0 ] && OUT="($DIFF)"
    RESULT="$RESULT""${LINE1%%,*}""$OUT,"   # append element and (diff),
    LINE1=${LINE1#*,} ; LINE2=${LINE2#*,}   # cut the first elements
done

echo "$RESULT" >"$1"                        #write outcome to FILE1
```